# Breakpoint not hit in assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am a newbie to assembly and this is the summary of what I have been doing, I intend to set a break point just before the point where `%eax` is loaded with `$Number` and then view the inserted value by issuing a `c` (continue) but the program shows it has set the break point and when I run it, it just does not hit the break point

Program:

```
.data
Number:
        .int 36
.text
        .globl _start
        _start:
        movl $Number, %eax
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

Assembling and Linking

```
root@bt:~/Arena# ls
a.s
root@bt:~/Arena# as --gstabs a.s
root@bt:~/Arena# ld -o out a.out 
root@bt:~/Arena# ./out 
root@bt:~/Arena#
```

At GDB

```
root@bt:~/Arena# gdb ./out 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu
Copyri  ... <blab> <blab> ...
Reading symbols from /root/Arena/out...done.
(gdb) list
1       .data
2       Number:
3               .int 36
4       .text
5               .globl _start
6               _start:
7               movl $Number, %eax
8               movl $1, %eax
9               movl $0, %ebx
10              int $0x80
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048074: file a.s, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/Arena/out 

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Might try a `nop` right after your `_start:` label. Seems to make gdb happier.

Comment: @Frank Kotler: Thanks, I can't believe that solved it. It really did make gdb a loaaat happier. But I'd like to make a note that `nop` is not required on Ubuntu 13.04 but is required on Ubuntu 10.04 versions and before.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. I have no idea what it means!

Comment: What if you assemble with -g instead of -gstabs?

Comment: I've hit this problem before. Breaking on the very first instruction in a program, so that the break must occur after the execve has loaded the process image but before userspace it returns to userspace, is a special case that wasn't handled correctly by the kernel and/or gdb. I'm pleased to hear that new versions do better with it though. It's not something you need for normal programs because they have the dynamic linker and other uninteresting stuff running before `main`.