# How to set breakpoint for start entry in ONLY data section program by GDB?

Tags: assembly, gdb, breakpoints, x86-64

I write a assembly program in my centos5_x64:

```
.data
.global _start
_start:
jmp f0
start:
pop %rsi
xor %rax,%rax
mov %al,7(%rsi)
mov %rsi,8(%rsi)
mov %rax,12(%rsi)
mov $0xb,%al
mov %rsi,%rbx
lea 8(%rsi),%rcx
xor %rdx,%rdx
int $0x80
f0:
call start
cmd: .ascii "/bin/shAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

It can be executed. I want to use gdb for debugging it, how I'd set breakpoint for `start` entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is assembled and linked with debug symbols, use:

```
(gdb) break start
```

Comment: Thanks, it can. But GDB can't break it on _start, why? Can i break it on the first instruction?

Comment: @5he1lc0de:  Have a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639893/breakpoint-not-hit-in-assembly?rq=1) which indicates that Ubuntu 10.04 and before plus the corresponding `gdb` had a weakness setting a breakpoint at the first instruction.  The solution seems to have been to add a `nop` there.